# APT-GET package errors

Tags: apt, package-management

I get msg:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I run:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

No packages are shown held.  Have not been able to figure out how to clear this.

All help appreciated!

TBNK

Comment: i'm trying to install WINE and looks like either 1.8 or 2.0 is the right version, but not sure as still on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Not allowed upgrade to 16.04 LTS until Oct 15 (18 months after release), since no LTS version is stable till 18 months out.

Comment: Have tried several reboots but nothing clears! Also edited the /etc/apt/sources.list file to take out any repositories that show errors or no connects.